# drop down list values not showing

Tags: javascript, html, json, perl

This is a very weird issue I'm facing on my webpage. I currently have a drop down list populated with data from a database using perl and javascript but the drop down list is not displaying the values I'm receiving from the database.

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
my $dataX = ${ConnectToDatabase($main::edsUGCar, $main::databaseEnv)};
$resultSet = $dataX->Execute("select vendor from dex_vendor_info group by vendor");

my @list_of_vendors;
while(!$resultSet->EOF) {
push @list_of_vendors, $resultSet->Fields("vendor")->Value;
    $resultSet->MoveNext;
}

$list_of_vendors_json = encode_json(\@list_of_vendors);

print <<ONE;
<html>
<body>
<h4> Test Vendor Array Javascript </h4>

<p id="demo"</p>
<form id="myForm">
<select id="selectNumber">
<option>Choose a Vendor</option>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
var list_of_vendors = $list_of_vendors_json;
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber"); 
for(var i = 0; i < list_of_vendors.length; i++) {
    var opt = list_of_vendors[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.text = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}​
</script>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
ONE
```

The HTML source for the output when I'm inspecting the dropdown list element shows:

```
<SELECT id=selectNumber> <OPTION selected>Choose a Vendor</OPTION> 
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript>
var list_of_vendors = ["3D Systems","3DSystems","3M"];
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber"); 
for(var i = 0; i < list_of_vendors.length; i++) {
    var opt = list_of_vendors[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.text = opt;
    el.value = opt ;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
</SCRIPT>
 <OPTION value="3D Systems"></OPTION> # Info Missing here after the `>`
 <OPTION value="3DSystems"></OPTION>
 <OPTION value="3M></OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: Include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY perl script.  Good on ya for the latter, but really need the former too and you've been on SO long enough to have heard this a few times already.

Comment: When I put `use strict` my website stopped working so I took it off

Comment: [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) is intended to tell you about problems with your code.  Instead of ignoring the problems, fix your code!

Comment: @Miller I understand the concept of use strict but I was given an application to add functionality to the perl script that is running on another server...This perl script has another perl module that it inherits from and is currently on another server.

Comment: @koala421: There is no reason why your application can't be coded with `use strict`, regardless of what modules it depends on. It is disrespectful of you to ask for help when you are ignoring the most basic debugging tools available to you. There is also little point in helping you to fix things until you have that in place

Comment: I assume your proprietary module is what provides `ConnectToDatabase`, `MoveNext` etc? It looks like an attempt to reinvent [`DBIx::Class`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class). I have never seen Perl code looking like jQuery before!

Comment: @Borodin I apologize for asking a question...The code given to me is 12 years old...I was asked to make updates to it so i thought I would give it a shot. Forgive me for not asking questions properly and wanting a quick and dirty answer.

Comment: @Borodin Also I'm not trying to be condescending in any way...I'm just fairly new to all this even though it says I've been a member for 2 years...

Comment: @koala421: There is no need for an apology. Just understand that your first step *must* be to get your program working with `use strict`, without just declaring all your variables at the start of the program! If you are having trouble getting it going then ask for help here, but explain that the code is old and you are trying to update it to modern Perl standards. A lot of the criticism you received was because we assumed that you wrote the program yourself, but you must *never* remove `use strict` to get your program running: you should *fix the problems* that it raises instead

Comment: @Borodin Thank you very much for the advice...I'll keep it in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the script out of the select tag? The DTD (HTML 4) states that select tags have the following structure:

```
<!ELEMENT SELECT - - (OPTGROUP|OPTION)+ -- option selector -->
```

Which basically means you can not omit the opening or closing `<select>` tag and *a `<select>` tag can only contain `<optgroup>` or `<option>` tags*, nothing else (no `<script>`)

Comment: I just tried that and it still is not giving me the right output...I think there is something wrong with the `document.createElement("option")` part of the javascript because I'm not getting the text portion after the `>` in `option` tag

Comment: I copied the output and tried to view it. In your output there are some weird symbols after the closing curly bracket, are those actually there? If I remove them, everything works.

Comment: Yeah, that's the same thing that happens with me that's why it's a little bizarre. Those symbols are coming from I don't know where..I was thinking it has something to do with Using JSON...

Comment: Maybe you accidentally entered them, but your editor does not show them? From your code I wouldn't know why JSON would have something to do with that.

Comment: I think my issue is that I have my `charset` of the frame set as `iso-8859-1` and JSON could be using `UTF-8` That's why the bogus characters are coming along for the ride

Answer (score 0):

In the section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var list_of_vendors = $list_of_vendors_json;
    var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber"); 
    for(var i = 0; i < list_of_vendors.length; i++) {
        var opt = list_of_vendors[i];
        var el = document.createElement("OPTION");
```

`el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(opt));` <--This line of code was missing!

```
        el.text = opt
        el.value = opt
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
</script>
```

Thanks CannibalGorilla for the suggestions...Appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem? If so then please edit it to make that more obvious. Please also accept it as a solution as soon as you are able, so that others can see that the issue is closed.